# this code works fine when a new table is to be added but fails when the same table is to be updated

Tags: php, mysql

when i try adding a new row of the 'syllabus' table
it works fine but when i try to update that same table,
the table is not updated. Instead it is redirected to
a blank page.I've used this same idea in adding and updating
various other tables.Adding is fine but in case of updating 
its the same story.

```
<?php
require('filehandler.php');//file handler
require('adminDB/sql_connect.php');
//password clean
function clean($string) {
    $string = str_replace(" ", "", $string);//Deletes the spaces.
    $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string);//Removes special chars.
    return preg_replace('/-+/', '', $string);//Replaces multiple hyphens with single one.
                        }
function sqli($string){
    $string = str_replace(";","",$string);
    $string = str_replace("OR","",$string);
    $string = str_replace("SELECT","",$string);
    $string = str_replace("FROM","",$string);
    $string = str_replace("DELETE","",$string);
    $string = str_replace("TRUNCATE","",$string);
    $string = str_replace("OR 1","",$string);
    $string = str_replace("UPDATE","",$string);
    return $string;

                    }

    $_POST = sqli($_POST);


    if(($_POST['add']=="SUBMIT")||($_POST['addpic']=="UPLOAD")){

    switch($_POST['data']){
        case 'syllabus':
        if($_SESSION['auth']=="special"){
        if(($_POST['syllabusReg']!="")&&($_FILES['syllabusLink']['name']!="")){
        //call to file handler for DOC
        $link=fileHandler($_FILES['syllabusLink'],"doc");
        if($link!="1"){
        $sql="INSERT INTO cse.syllabus (syllabus_reg,syllabus_link) 
        VALUES ('".$_POST['syllabusReg']."','".$link."');";}}}
        else{header('Location:../home.php');exit;}
        break;}
        }
    //**Update part**

        if($_POST['update']=="UPDATE"){
        //Protects against SQL Injection
        $id=stripslashes($_POST['id']);
        $id=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
    switch($_POST['data']){
        case 'syllabus':
        if($_SESSION['auth']=="special"){
        $sql="UPDATE cse.syllabus SET syllabus_reg='".$_POST['syllabusReg']."'
        WHERE syllabus_id='".$id."';";}else{header('Location:../home.php');exit;}
        break;}
        }
?>
```

//*****************************sql file*************************
//sql_connect.php

```
    <?php

if(!isset($_SESSION)){
define('SQL_HOST','localhost');
define('SQL_USER','cse.visitor');
define('SQL_PASS','dfdfdff');
define('SQL_DB','cse');
}
else if(($_SESSION['auth']=='a')||($_SESSION['auth']=='b')){
define('SQL_HOST','localhost');
define('SQL_USER','cse.staff.a');
define('SQL_PASS','ssAn');
define('SQL_DB','cse');
}
else if(($_SESSION['auth']=='c')||($_SESSION['auth']=='d')){
define('SQL_HOST','localhost');
define('SQL_USER','cse.staff.z');
define('SQL_PASS','ssa6');
define('SQL_DB','cse');
}
else if($_SESSION['auth']=='special'){
define('SQL_HOST','localhost');
define('SQL_USER','cse.admin');
define('SQL_PASS','ksjfdMRsf');
define('SQL_DB','cse');
}
```

//Attempting to establish a connection

```
$connect = mysql_connect(SQL_HOST, SQL_USER, SQL_PASS)
or die("Check your server connection.<p><strong>Error</strong>". "Description :".mysql_error());
```

//Selecting the required database
    $res = mysql_select_db(SQL_DB);

```
?>
```

Comment: So, your code can do an `INSERT` and `UPDATE` with one `POST`?

Comment: I cant actually see any code that does execute your $sql...It might be a good idea to show this code as well.

Comment: @Jojo :Is it possible that my table is not being updated due to resticted permissons?

Comment: @Biotox:Its actually part of a big code with similar logic.

Comment: I think you should check if this works if($_SESSION['auth']=="special"){ properly. print_r($_SESSION['auth']); if it does really equal to "special".

Because you said on your post, "Instead it is redirected to a blank page." So yeah, that's the only header() function that I can see in your update code area.

Comment: Still I don´t see any code that does actually execute your update-sql. What we see is how you connect to your database. Connection should be ok as you would see your die()-Message instead. Besides, I do hope that the passwords are not the real ones ;) And yes, it *might* be a permission problem. try the mysql_error function (http://de2.php.net/mysql_error) right after executing your query and after you verified that you are actually getting there as Craftein suggested.

Comment: @Craftein :You were right. I need to import the page that verifies it. Thanks.

Comment: @Jojo : The passwords are not the real ones :P Thanks.